# Discordjs v12 | cannot find module ../undefined/help.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My bot has a command located in /commands/developer/reload.js and it's purpose is to unload a command then load it again. But when trying to find the commands folder it throws an error saying `Cannot find module '../undefined/help.js'` but the path is `../misc/help.js`

Code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    name: 'reload',
    description: 'Reloads a command',
    args: true,
    usage: '<command_name>',
    cooldown: 1,
    aliases: ['rl', 'restart'],
    execute(message, args) {
        const commandName = args[0].toLowerCase();
        const command = message.client.commands.get(commandName) || message.client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

        if(!command) {
            return message.channel.send(`There is no command called '${commandName}'`);
        }
        // commandFolders returns undefined
        const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');
        // Also returns undefined
        const folderName = commandFolders.find(folder => {
            fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).includes(`${command.name}.js`);
        })
        // Command errors out here
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`../${folderName}/${command.name}.js`)];
        
        // This part never runs.
        try {
            const newCommand = require(`../${folderName}/${command.name}.js`);
            message.client.commands.set(newCommand.name, newCommand);
            message.channel.send(`Command '${newCommand.name}' was reload successfully`)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send(`There was an error while reloading a Command.`)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You obviously aren't requiring it properly, can you show exactly where you are requiring it?

Comment: i am requiring on the try block as the variable newCommand

Comment: I see... folderName is undefined for some reason

Comment: Is someone yet to find an answer for my question?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the folder as undefined is because you are not returning the folder you are trying to find in the `folderName` function. It is trying to find a folder with the command and even if it does, you are not doing anything with it, you are not returning it or logging it into the console. So you just have to return it, the `folderName` function might look something like this:

```js
const folderName = commandFolders.find(folder => fs.readdirSync(`commands/${folder}`).includes(`${command.name}.js`)) // If you want a one-liner
// Or
const folderName = commandFolders.find(folder => {
    return fs.readdirSync(`commands/${folder}`).includes(`${command.name}.js`)
})
```

If the error persists, the error is most likely there because the path is not correct. So in that case, please provide the folder structure of your bot

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem, please accept the answer as it will help people to see the correct solution for your problem